# iOS AVPlayerViewController does not hide playback controls for audio-only asset

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I noticed that when I load a AVMutableComposition into AVPlayerViewController with only audio tracks, the playback controls does not auto hide.

I would like it to have it auto hide the same way as when I load video compositions.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround that I've seen is to just add an empty video track.

```
// just a hack to get an empty video track
mediaTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                               preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
```